# Is there a way to join tables in gtsummary to obtain CIs?

Tags: r, gtsummary

I have successfully calculated confidence intervals in a table but unable to join the two tables to have one. It seem not to work. The desired output is to have the Interestingly there is no error.

```
library(gtsummary)
library(tidyverse)

tbl2 <-
  trial %>%
  mutate(trt = as.factor(trt)) %>%
  select(grade, response, trt) %>%
  tbl_summary(missing = "no",  type = everything() ~ "categorical")

myci2 <- tbl2$meta_data %>%
  filter(summary_type %in% c("categorical", "dichotomous")) %>%
  select(summary_type, var_label, df_stats) %>%
  unnest(df_stats) %>%
  mutate(
    conf.low = (p - qnorm(0.975) * sqrt(p * (1 - p) / N)) %>%
      style_percent(symbol = TRUE),
    conf.high =( p + qnorm(0.975) * sqrt(p * (1 - p) / N)) %>%
      style_percent(symbol = TRUE),
    ci = str_glue("{conf.low}, {conf.high}"),
    label = coalesce(variable_levels, var_label),
    row_type = ifelse(summary_type == "dichotomous", "label", "level")
  ) %>%
  select(variable, row_type, label, ci)


finaltbl <- tbl2 %>%
  modify_table_body(
    left_join,
    myci2,
    by = c("variable", "row_type", "label")
  )
```

Comment: Please supply (a sample of) your data.

Comment: trial data is in the gtsummary package

Comment: When you load the package the dataset will be available. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the new column is, by default, hidden from the output. You can unhide a column by either assigning a header with `modify_header()` or with `modify_column_unhide()`.

```r
library(gtsummary)
#> #BlackLivesMatter
library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: package 'readr' was built under R version 4.1.1
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.4.2'

tbl2 <-
  trial %>%
  mutate(trt = as.factor(trt)) %>%
  select(grade, response, trt) %>%
  tbl_summary(missing = "no",  type = everything() ~ "categorical")

myci2 <- 
  tbl2$meta_data %>%
  filter(summary_type %in% c("categorical", "dichotomous")) %>%
  select(summary_type, var_label, df_stats) %>%
  unnest(df_stats) %>%
  mutate(
    conf.low = (p - qnorm(0.975) * sqrt(p * (1 - p) / N)) %>%
      style_percent(symbol = TRUE),
    conf.high =( p + qnorm(0.975) * sqrt(p * (1 - p) / N)) %>%
      style_percent(symbol = TRUE),
    ci = str_glue("{conf.low}, {conf.high}"),
    label = coalesce(variable_levels, var_label),
    row_type = ifelse(summary_type == "dichotomous", "label", "level")
  ) %>%
  select(variable, row_type, label, ci)


finaltbl <- 
  tbl2 %>%
  modify_table_body(
    left_join,
    myci2,
    by = c("variable", "row_type", "label")
  ) %>% 
  # adding a column header UNHIDES the column (you could also use `modify_column_unhide()`)
  modify_header(ci = "**95% CI**")
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2021-09-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

FYI, in the next version of gtsummary, there is a function that will add the CI and you won't need to calculate it yourself: `add_ci()`.

Comment: This is good news!